# missing method body, or declare abstract java error

Tags: java

A snapshot of the code and error being presented

[image]

I've tried making class `main()` I've tried adding `{}` neither have worked, please help.

Comment: You're missing `{` and `}` after your `main` method declaration.

Comment: Please copy and paste this code into the editor and format it as code, it will be much easier to read. Also, you should do the same with the error message.

Comment: This doesn't look like `Typo`, it is even more crazy.

Comment: @ChedMyers You can take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a `{` after `main()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//-------------------------------------^
```

And after `return` add `;` and `}`.

Looks like you are confusing between Java and .NET. There's no `Console.WriteLine()` in Java. You need to change it to:

```
System.out.println();
```

The `Console.WriteLine()` is available only in .NET Framework. You need to replace them with the above. For eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("john smith");
```

Should be replaced with:

```
System.out.println("john smith");
```

If you really want to execute `Console.WriteLine`, then you need to use Microsoft Visual Studio and create a new **C# Console Application**.

See more here: [How to: Create a C# Console Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/0wc2kk78(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

[image]
<sub>(source: [programcall.com](http://images.programcall.com/Console-Application-in-CS.jpg))</sub>

And in the Console Program using .NET, it uses the main class as:

```
class Program {
```

And not the one which you use. So definitely yours is a **Java Application**.

Comment: Thanks boss, really helped me out :D I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some brackets.

```
public class MyFirstProgram {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Console.WriteLine("some text");

    }

}
```

EDIT: You should also add semicolons `;` to the end of a function/line

Answer (score 0):

For every method with implementation, you need a pair of curly braces.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

The curly braces will indicate the scope of the codes the follows. Also, are you asking a question on C# or Java?

---

If you are asking a question on Java and not C#, to print a line, you should be using `System.out.print()` or `System.out.println()`. Not `Console.WriteLine()`.

It looks like to me you are writing **C#** codes in **Java** with a habit carried over from **C++**. There is no need to write a return statement at the end of your main method in Java.

The return type for `main()` in Java is `void`, that means you can't return a value from `main()`.

---

Your complete program in **Java** shall look like this:

```
public class MyFirstProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   //<--curly bracket needed
        System.out.println("john smith");
        System.out.println("programming major");
        //more println statements below..
    }   //<--curly bracket needed
}
```

Comment: Java. Not C#. Just Java.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Java with `Console.WriteLine()`? Well, I may be ignorant on this, but I only use `System.out.println()` and never `Console.WriteLine` in Java.

Comment: @user3437460 Just saw sorry. **Sorry**.